# How to sort and remove tuples with same first element and only keeping the first occurrence

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, duplicates, tuples

Support we have a list of tuples listeT:

```
ListeT=[('a', 1), ('x',1) , ('b', 1), ('b', 1),  ('a', 2),  ('a',3),  ('c', 6), ('c', 5),('e', 6),  ('d', 7),('b', 2)]` and i want to get the following result:
```

Result = [('a', 1), ('x',1) , ('b', 1), ('c', 5), ('c', 6), ('e', 6),  ('d', 7)]`

1-I want to order this list according to the second element of tuples.
2- I want to remove duplicates and only keep the first occurrence of tuples having the same value of first elements: For instance if have  ('a', 1) and (a,2), I want to keep only ('a', 1).
For the sorting I used : res=sorted(listT, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse= True) and it worked.
But for the duplicates I could't find a good solution:
I can remove duplicate elements by converting the the list to a set (`set(listeT)`) or by using
`numpy.unique(ListeT, axis=0)`. However, this only removes the duplicates for all the tuples but I want also to remove the duplicates of tuples having the same first element and only keeping the first occurrence.
Thank you.

Comment: does the order of the elements in the answer important to you?

Comment: Yes, the first step is to order them according the second element of the tuple. Ordered_listeT= 

Support we have a list of tuples listeT:

ListeT=[('a', 1), ('x',1) , ('b', 1), ('b', 1),  ('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('a',3),  , ('c', 5), ('c', 6)('e', 6),  ('d', 7)]

Comment: I understand. I am asking if the order in the end results is important, for ex: `[('x', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 1), ('e', 6), ('c', 5), ('d', 7)]` is it sufficient? same as your answer but different order

Answer (score 3):

The `dict` can take care of the uniqueness while feeding it in reversed order.
I did not understood if you need the outer `sort` so you can just replace it with `list()` if not needed.

```
sorted(dict(sorted(ListeT, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse= True)).items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('x', 1), ('c', 5), ('e', 6), ('d', 7)]
```

Comment: Great compact solution.  It's prob. too `dense` and hard to read?  Will be more readable by breaking into 2 steps instead maybe: dict_sorted =  dict(sorted(listT, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse= True))
                 #   key=lambda x: x[1])


result = sorted(dict_sorted.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

Comment: note that in earlier python versions dict are not ordered, idk if that going to impact your solution but worth checking :)